# Python can't find xpath for spotify scroll box

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: The scroll box is on the side]So basically I'm learning python and thought it would be fun to make a bot that goes into Spotify and gives you back the songs you have liked but not in a playlist. Spotify has some weird feature in the player that doesn't let you inspect a specific element so I have to search through the inspector to find the scroll box in liked songs. I'm trying to save the path to scroll_box but it just sends back:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".scroller.context-event"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
```

I've tried so many variations of find_element_by and so many paths and I can not get it. In the end I need to to scroll down the box and load all songs and then ill work from there. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from secrets import pw2
from secrets import email
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Spotbot:
    def __init__(self, email, username, pw2):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://spotify.com')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")\
            .click()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
            .send_keys(email)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
            .send_keys(pw2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")\
            .click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks')
        sleep(2)
        #scroll_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/section/ol')
        page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]')
        self.driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);""", page)
        sleep(10)



Spotbot(email, 'kallen_selby', pw2)
```

Heres the link to the scroll box: https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks
Pls help I'm really lost...

Comment: which element are you trying to handle ? Can you give some more detaails because xpath is not going to help to locate your element on site

Comment: I'm trying to scroll down the list of songs. So I don't want to scroll the page down but the list of songs within the page.  https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll using javascript, not sure what you mean by 'scroll box':

```
#Specific height (1080 pixel in my monitor)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080);")

#Bottom of page
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html')
driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);""", page)
```

Comment: Yes, I have to figure out ho;w to scroll so that helps nut how do I tell it to scroll the specific "box" that holds the songs and not the page?

Comment: also when i run this script it doesn't scroll down because the actual page cant scroll down only the box within the page. what i need to do is the part where you wrote /html and i need it to go farther but whenever i do it gives the error message

Comment: I updated it to page=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/section/ol')
  self.driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);""", page)
  sleep(10)  But nothing happens, but i get no error

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the solution to my own problem:)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from secrets import pw2
from secrets import email
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Spotbot:
    def __init__(self, email, username, pw2):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://spotify.com')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")\
            .click()
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
            .send_keys(email)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
            .send_keys(pw2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")\
            .click()
        sleep(2)

    def get_liked_songs(self):
        self.driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/collection/tracks')
        sleep(2)
        #(/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2])
        scroll_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div')
        last_ht, ht = 0, 1
        while last_ht != ht:
            last_ht = ht
            sleep(1)
            ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); 
                return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                """, scroll_box)
        sleep(1)
        liked_songs= scroll_box.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        songs= [name.text for name in liked_songs if name != '']
        print(songs)






my_bot = Spotbot(email, 'kallen_selby', pw2)
my_bot.get_liked_songs()
```

so i just needed to back up the xpath and then use a while loop to scroll until i couldn't any more.